# express middleware not sending response

Tags: express

I have a delete route that has 2 middleware functions Authcontroller.protect and authcontroller.restrictTo("admin, "lead-guide")

```
router
  .delete(
    authController.protect,
    authController.restrictTo("admin", "lead-guide"),
    tourController.deleteTour
  );
```

Within restrictTo I have a check to see if the user has the proper "role" to perform that task and if they don't, express is supposed ot send a 403. I'm seeing that express never actually sends the response. it enters the if statement(i see the console successfully printing fialure) and then it just skips sending the response.

```
exports.restrictTo = (...roles) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.user.role);
    if (!roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
      console.log("failure");
      return res.status(403).json({
        status: fail,
        message: "you do not have permission to perform this action"
      });
      console.log(req, res);
    }
    next();
  };
};
```

Comment: Put a `try/catch` in your inner function and see if there's an exception being thrown.  For example, what is `fail`?  Is that defined somewhere in this context?  Put a breakpoint in the inner function and step through it and see exactly what is happening.  This is elemental debugging.  If you learn how to do it, it will save you a lot of time solving future problems.

Comment: Oh good call on the try/catch. It pointed me to the fail value, which is supposed to be a string. That fixed the issue. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `try/catch` in your inner function and see if there's an exception being thrown.

From looking at your code, if the `fail` variable (which you don't show a definition for) is not defined, then that would throw an exception and keep the `res.json()` from executing.